# Find a string within a string in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to find a string withing a string. In Oracle I used `regexp_like` but I don't see such function in SQL Server 2016.  I have a table that has an address column such as:

```
ADDRESS
--------
345 E 149 ST NY NY
345 EAST 149 STREET NY NY
444 CHEST AVE NY NY
444 CHEST AVENUE NY NY
```

I want to write a query that search for 345 [E OR East] follow by 149.  in the case of 444 chest, I want a query to search for 444 chest[ ave or avenue].

I have something like the following which doesn't work

```
select * from table1 where address like '345[EEAST] 149%'
```

Basically I want to tell the query to get any address that start with 345 E or 345 EAST follow by 149.

Can someone help me write a query for this?  I know I can use OR clause with two different address but if I have multiple addresses with different pattern then OR clause will not be efficient method. I'm looking into using some type of regular expression.

Comment: Have a look at [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but you need to add the wildcard `%` for it to be any use. Otherwise try charindex or patindex. Thats what is on offer with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the amount of support for LIKE expression is very limited currently in SQL Server. Your requirement can be satisfied by below queries

```
DECLARE @table table(address VARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @table
values
('345 E 149 ST NY NY')
,('345 EAST 149 STREET NY NY')
,('444 CHEST AVE NY NY')
,('444 CHEST AVENUE NY NY')


SELECT * FROM @table WHERE Address LIKE '345 E%149 ST% NY NY'

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE Address LIKE '444 CHEST AVE% NY NY'
```

**Result Set**

```
+---------------------------+
|          address          |
+---------------------------+
| 345 E 149 ST NY NY        |
| 345 EAST 149 STREET NY NY |
+---------------------------+


+------------------------+
|        address         |
+------------------------+
| 444 CHEST AVE NY NY    |
| 444 CHEST AVENUE NY NY |
+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LIKE` operator, with separate conditions for each match:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '345 E 149 %' OR ADDRESS LIKE '345 EAST 149 %';
```

Comment: hi Tim, thanks for your reply.  I am aware that i can use OR but as stated in my original post i can have different pattern of the same address.  if i use OR then i have to use an OR for each different pattern of the same address.  im looking for regular expression without using OR

Comment: @yoohoo did you try `LIKE '345 % 149 %'`?

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server has no native regex support.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in `WHERE` Clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM   @T
WHERE  (
           1 = CASE 
                    WHEN ADDRESS LIKE '%345_E_149%' THEN 1
                    WHEN ADDRESS LIKE '%345_EAST_149%' THEN 1
                    WHEN ADDRESS LIKE '%444_CHEST_AVE%' THEN 1
                    WHEN ADDRESS LIKE '%444_CHEST_AVENUE%' THEN 1
               END
       )
```